# Checking if a value is within a time range

Tags: go, interval

How can I improve the style to avoid so many `float64()`s?

```
func IsInTimeRange(tvalue int32,timeout int){
    t := time.Now().Unix()
    return int(math.Abs(float64(t)-float64(tvalue))) < timeout
}
```

Comment: start with running [gofmt](https://blog.golang.org/go-fmt-your-code) on your code

Comment: thanks.   I'm not comfortable with so many "float64" in major.

Comment: What is the origin of the `tvalue` and `timeout` values.  Without a common basis in `time.Time`, there is no way to compare them relative to a current time.

Comment: You have a `return` in a function with no return type in its signature.  Why not get your code to compile before posting it?

Comment: Sorry . It's hard to write code in textarea. 
I will pay attention nexttime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example,

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func IsInTimeRange(tvalue int32, timeout int) bool {
    delta := int(time.Now().Unix() - int64(tvalue))
    return -timeout < delta && delta < timeout
}

func main() {}
```

`tvalue int32` will overflow in [year 2038](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem), change it to `tvalue int64`.

```
package main

import "time"

func IsInTimeRange(tvalue int64, timeout int) bool {
    delta := int(time.Now().Unix() - tvalue)
    return -timeout < delta && delta < timeout
}

func main() {}
```

Comment: tvalue maybe negative by bad call.    
What a pity , there are no function overloading in golang

Comment: I have no idea that what's `int64` safe in python with Thrift,so I choose int32.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to convert to `float64` only to use `math.Abs`. This is complete overkill. `Abs` for integers is a trivial (if you can neglect overflow as in your example) `if` statement.

(Background: `math.Abs` exists to handle NaNs and Infs properly.)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a full answer, but might still be of interest.

As already stated; `math.Abs` is overkill for integer absolutes. And writing your own `Abs` function is trivial.

But if you want one, the fastest way to do it can be found in the `png` package:

```
func Abs(x int) int {
    // intSize is either 32 or 64.
    const intSize = 32 << (^uint(0) >> 63)

    // m := -1 if x < 0. m := 0 otherwise.
    m := x >> (intSize - 1)

    // In two's complement representation, the negative number
    // of any number (except the smallest one) can be computed
    // by flipping all the bits and add 1. This is faster than
    // code with a branch.
    // See Hacker's Delight, section 2-4.
    return (x ^ m) - m
}
```